# d3.js forced graph dealing with 10.000 data entries

Tags: d3.js

Is it possible to render a huge forced graph on server-side? Or to implement any kind of existing plugin, logic etc. which could deal with huge amount of data, to reduce lags?

My current graph contains 120-150 nodes but will drastically increase during the upcoming months. A  performance test with 10.000 confirmed my thoughts, the usability is completely gone.

I found a stackoverflow thread from 7 years ago but since time passed so does technology. Any best practice out there, which I missed?

Comment: What is the number of links (relatively to the number of nodes)?

Comment: Mostly even for now but will be clearly more in future. Like a spider net with several connections.

Comment: Useful ? https://gist.github.com/DavidDeSimone/1a32a97913360c8e181e

Comment: looks promising, still I assume a server-pre-rendered solution would be the best. I increased the mentioned example up to 5000 nodes and its laggy. Maybe this + pre-rendered does the job. Thanks for mentioning.